# Get etree Element with attribute, or containing subelement with attribute

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have an XML file to parse, and I need to find elements by id.

In the example code, I need to find the name of the `driver`, but I don't know whether my id is for the `vehicle`, `engine`, or `block`. I would like a solution which would work with arbitrary xml inside of `vehicle` (but existence of `driver` is guaranteed).

```
<road>
    <vehicle id="16">
        <driver>Bob Johnson</driver>
        <engine id="532">
            <type>V8</type>
            <block id="113">
                <material>Aluminium</material>
            </block>
        </engine>
    </vehicle>
    <vehicle id="452">
        <driver>Dave Edwards</driver>
        <engine id="212">
            <type>Inline 6</type>
            <block id="381">
                <material>Cast Iron</material>
            </block>
        </engine>
    </vehicle>
</road>
```

**What have I tried**

I was trying to get the elements by their id, and then, if they weren't `vehicle` tags, navigate up the tree to find it, but it seems python's `elem.find()` returns None if the result is outside `elem`.

Looking at [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element%22the%20docs%22), they have this example:

```
# Nodes with name='Singapore' that have a 'year' child
root.findall(".//year/..[@name='Singapore']")
```

But I don't see how to make that work for any descendant, as opposed to a decendant on a specific level.

Comment: May be it is a matter of a personal preference, but since you are eventually using `lxml.etree`, I think `ancestor-or-self` should be preferred. Pretty sure it would be faster as well from the performance perspective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note**: All the snippets below use `lxml` library. To install, run: `pip install lxml`.

You should use `root.xpath(..)` not `root.findall(..)`.

```
>>> root.xpath("//vehicle/driver/text()")
['Bob Johnson', 'Dave Edwards']
```

If you want to extract driver's name from a given ID, you'd do:

```
>>> vehicle_id = "16"
>>> xpath("//vehicle[@id='16' or .//*[@id='16']]/driver/text()")
['Bob Johnson']
```

UPDATE: To get the driver's name for a given `id` nested at any level deeper, you'd do:

```
>>> i = '16'
>>> a.xpath("//vehicle[@id='%s' or .//*[@id='%s']]/driver/text()"%(i,i))
['Bob Johnson']
>>> i = '532'
>>> a.xpath("//vehicle[@id='%s' or .//*[@id='%s']]/driver/text()"%(i,i))
['Bob Johnson']
>>> i = '113'
>>> a.xpath("//vehicle[@id='%s' or .//*[@id='%s']]/driver/text()"%(i,i))
['Bob Johnson']
```

Comment: OK, but how do I find which one is for my id? If I have id of '381', how do I know that's for "Dave Edwards", not "Bob Johnson"?

Comment: Can you explain? Do you want to find a driver, for a vehicle with a given ID?

Comment: Yes, or for the vehicle which contains the element with the given id. My id could be for the vehicle, engine, or block, but I need to find the driver.

Comment: I'm getting an error:  `AttributeError: 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element' object has no attribute 'xpath'`

I'm loading my XML like:
    `tree = etree.parse('file.xml')`  
    `root = tree.getroot()`  

Do I need to load this differently? Do I need a seperate library for this?

Comment: Are you using `lxml` ? `from lxml import etree` ? **Edit**: Probably not. Please use `lxml` library to do all XML specific operations. The `ElementTree` that comes out of the box lacks many standard features.

Comment: I've moved to lxml, and things are working now. Thanks. (If you want to edit your answer to state that requirement, then I'll accept it).

Comment: @nHaskins: Yeah, I should have mentioned it long ago. Would have avoided the confusion. Fixed it now. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you know the `id`, but don't know if this `id` is from vehicle, engine or block, you can approach it with an XPath expression, but you would have to use [`lxml.etree`](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html) instead of `xml.etree.ElementTree` (it has very limited XPath support). Use the [`ancestor-or-self`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/ancestor-or-self) axis:

```
input_id = "your ID"
print(root.xpath(".//*[@id='%s']/ancestor-or-self::vehicle/driver" % input_id)[0].text)
```

This would print:

- `Bob Johnson` if `input_id` would be `16` or `532` or `113`
- `Dave Edwards` if `input_id` would be `452` or `212` or `381`

---

Complete working example:

```
import lxml.etree as ET

data = """
<road>
    <vehicle id="16">
        <driver>Bob Johnson</driver>
        <engine id="532">
            <type>V8</type>
            <block id="113">
                <material>Aluminium</material>
            </block>
        </engine>
    </vehicle>
    <vehicle id="452">
        <driver>Dave Edwards</driver>
        <engine id="212">
            <type>Inline 6</type>
            <block id="381">
                <material>Cast Iron</material>
            </block>
        </engine>
    </vehicle>
</road>
"""

root = ET.fromstring(data)
for input_id in [16, 532, 113, 452, 212, 381]:
    print(root.xpath(".//*[@id='%s']/ancestor-or-self::vehicle/driver" % input_id)[0].text)
```

Prints:

```
Bob Johnson
Bob Johnson
Bob Johnson
Dave Edwards
Dave Edwards
Dave Edwards
```